# Unix (ksh) script to read file, parse and output certain columns only

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have an input file that looks like this:

```
"LEVEL1","cn=APP_GROUP_ABC,ou=dept,dc=net","uid=A123456,ou=person,dc=net"
"LEVEL1","cn=APP_GROUP_DEF,ou=dept,dc=net","uid=A123456,ou=person,dc=net"
"LEVEL1","cn=APP_GROUP_ABC,ou=dept,dc=net","uid=A567890,ou=person,dc=net"
```

I want to read each line, parse and then output like this:

```
A123456,ABC
A123456,DEF
A567890,ABC
```

In other words, retrieve the user id from "uid=" and then the identifier from "cn=APP_GROUP_".  Repeat for each input record, writing to a new output file.

Note that the column positions aren't fixed, so can't rely on positions, guessing I have to search for the "uid=" string and somehow use the position maybe?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: And what have you tried?  This is not a code writing service.

Comment: NathanOliver, I am not asking for code writing, where did I ask that?  Just a pointer as to what command or syntax is all I am looking for, to then go and do more research and write the code myself.  Thanks for your constructive help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk to split in columns, split by ',' and then split by =, and grab the result. You can do it easily as `awk -F, '{ print $5}' | awk -F= '{print $2}'`

Take a look at this line looking at the example you provided:

```
cat file  | awk -F, '{ print $5}' | awk -F= '{print $2}'
A123456
A123456
A567890
```

Comment: Many thanks Breno Leitao, this looks just what I am after.  I will test out some example code.

Comment: Cool. Could you please mark my qustion as correct, then, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*cn=APP_GROUP_\([^,]*\).*uid=\([^,]*\).*/\2,\1/'
```

The regex captures the two desired strings, and outputs them in reverse order with a comma between them. You might need to change the context of the captures, depending on the precise nature of your data, because the `uid=` will match the *last* `uid=` in the line, if there are more than one.